# Shopify Storefront GraphQL API get list of available countries and states/provinces (WITHOUT REST API)

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

Requirement: **Do not use the Shopify Admin Rest API**

How do I get a list of the countries and their states/provinces with the Storefront GraphQL API?

I am creating a page in React where a customer can edit their address. For my `<Select>` fields, for countries and provinces, I want to use the Storefront GraphQL API because that is what all of the other queries in my React site are written with.

I tried this query but it looks like the states/provinces are not available to be retrieved. Why are the states/provinces not available here?

https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-01/objects/Country#fields

```
{
  localization {
    availableCountries {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Has the store actually added any countries to the list of countries it allows? If you get back an empty result, it could just be the store has no countries enabled in it. Try enabling one and see what you get.

Comment: No modifications like that have been made. Everything works as expected in the live code base built with Shopify's Liquid.